# How to migrate from postgresql to sqlite3 in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was using postgresql for my project, but I have to package (into a zip file) my project along with the populated database.

How do I transfer/migrate data from postgresql to sqlite3?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of your data is in models, `dumpdata` and `loaddata` should do the trick. I've had to do some massaging in the past, such as with Django's `content_types` table.

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata

Good luck!